# VSpackage how to call operations on the project

Tags: visual-studio, vspackage

Is there a way In a VSpackage to issue a clean on the project from code, to issue a rebuild or a build. So basically is there a way in code to call the commands that appears in the context menu when you left click on a project? (though my current context may not be in solution explorer I may be on the editor window, so calling `ExecuteCommand` wont work for commands that are only available when I am in the solution explorer)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [SolutionBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.solutionbuild.aspx)-interface offers various methods that allow performing actions on the solution, e.g. building the solution or a project and cleaning the solution.

You start at the DTE-object and access the SolutionBuild like this:

```
// Builds the solution and waits for the build to finish
DTE.Solution.SolutionBuild.Build(true); 
// Show result of build
MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} projects failed to build.", 
                   DTE.Solution.SolutionBuild.LastBuildInfo));
```

Comment: Brilliant! Just what the Doc ordered (pun unintended)!